# how to stop visualizing this element in gwt?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

i'm new in google web toolkit.I should stop visualizing one of the elements in my home page.The element is on the bottom of the page and shows info about the project.When press right mouse button and inspect element it shows me a html code.I delete the code for that element,but just for next refresh.How to stop showing this element?

Thanks in advance!
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the html code in your browser does not change your code!

You have to change the source code of your gwt application. The html code which is loaded in your browser is the compiled/generated html code from your gwt application source code.

So, if you are using UiBinding, then you have to find the ui.xml file which contains the element you want to remove. If you are not using UiBinding then the element is created in a gwt/java view class. So you have to find the gwt/java view class which creates the element.

Comment: If my answer solved your question, we could tag it tag it as accepted response